# How to call service from other than controller

Tags: symfony

How to call service from other than controller

I have services like this

```
<?php
namespace Acme\TopBundle\MyServices;


class MyFunc
{
    public function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
        //

        return $randomString;
    }
}
```

I can call this service from controller

```
$this->get('myfunc')->generateRandomString()
```

But from outside of the controller

```
$this->get('myfunc')->generateRandomString()
```

shows

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\LessonAdmin::get() in
```

and

```
$this->container->get('myfunc')->generateRandomString()
```

shows

```
Undefined property: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\UserAdmin::$container in /Users/daichi/httproot/muty/src/Acme/AdminBundle/Admin/UserAdmin.php
```

How can I call services from outside of the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to access the container or any other services is to use the dependency injection component.

You can find more about it in the [documentation of dependency injection component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html). 
I would advise you to create a service and you can find how to create one here [service container documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).